# Auto Layout of a UIViewController in Code using the Visual Formatting Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'd like to position a view *emptyAddButton* on the bottom left using auto layout in Code using the visual formatting language. Here's my current approach.

Initializing the button *emptyAddButton*, a custom UIViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
...
        emptyAddButton = [[AddCardViewController alloc] init];
        [emptyAddButton.view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 300, 190, 65)]; //to define width + height. x, y is random and should be overwritten by auto auto layout
        [self addChildViewController:emptyAddButton];
        [emptyAddButton.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:emptyAddButton.view];
...
}
```

Assigning the Auto Layout for bottom left position + padding (10)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
...
    NSDictionary *viewToLayout = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:emptyAddButton.view forKey:@"emptyAddButton"];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[emptyAddButton]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewToLayout]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[emptyAddButton]-(10)-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewToLayout]];
...
}
```

Currently the *emptyAddButton* does not show up at all.

Any idea how to position the view correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set a frame, turn off autoresizing masks and also add constraints - it will be discarding your frame and recalculating to zero width and height. You can confirm this by logging out the subviews of your view controller.

Add the size to the VFL strings as well :

```
"H:|-(10)-[emptyAddButton(==190)]"
```

And the same for the vertical constraint.

As an aside, there is no merit in splitting the creation of the view and the setup of the constraints. Do it all at once (I'd do it in viewDidLoad). At the moment you are re-creating the constraints every time the view appears.